# Снова про Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, progress-bar

У мен возникла такая проблема: я нашел на гитхабе [вот эту библиотеку](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress/), реализующую круглый прогрессбар, но она почему-то отказывается работать. Я добавил в pom.xml зависимость, указанную на странице проекта, собрал проект, все вроде получилось - ошибок нет.
Но когда я добавил разметку в свою активити то получил ошибку такого вида:

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'arc_progress' in package

Кроме того еще такая странная вещь: несмотря на то что проект скомпилировался, в Maven Dependencies не появилась эта библиотека.

Как это можно исправить, может кто знает?

Answer (score 1):

[Пример от mkyoung](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/), запусти:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\kaptcha-{version}.jar -DgroupId=com.google.code -DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar
```

И подключи:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code</groupId>
      <artifactId>kaptcha</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
 </dependency>
```